# Вставка оформлена симметричными знаками, - можно? или что-то (что?) убрать?

Tags: пунктуация

> Однако действующие лица, словно сошедшие
>   с триумфального римского рельефа, – те же ракурсы в полупрофиль, так
>   же щедро струятся потоки одежд, – приближены к нам, мы пока ещё не
>   видим фигуры, как это будет впоследствии принято, в полный рост.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Оставляем симметричные знаки**, разрешенные Розенталем. Это связано с распространенностью вставки, пусть она будет именно симметричной, так удобнее читать ее как вставку.

Формально можно убрать вторую запятую, но нового понимания текста это не даст, а графику испортит.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню комментарий Розенталя, он упоминал симметрию с двойными знаками препинания лишь как встречающееся в корректорской практике явление, т. е. циркулярами не прописанное. Потому запятую при втором тире можно убрать - она не закрывает никаких оборотов, ценных для учебного разбора предложения, на котором пока что держится современная пунктуация, щедрая на знаки. Я в таких случаях вспоминаю Гиппократа: можно не ставить - не ставлю, тем более, что нового вида "препинания" сдвоенный знак не обозначает; эстетичность же такой симметрии спорна.

Comment: У, змий. А то, что вставка ОБЪЁМНАЯ, кагбэ не в счёт? Срочно поставь пятёрку за умнейший-сложнейший вопрос - я чётных цифр на дух не переношу! Будь ласка.

Comment: Чего в ней объёмного - два места багажа через одну запятую? С арифметичекой точки зрения здесь _нечётная симметрия_ - запятая (будь она неладна) оба раза слева.

Comment: Фу ты. Я у себя в репе чётных не переношу... Единицу, что ль, кому за ответ поставить...

Answer (score 1):

Предложение распространенное, изобилует запятыми. Я бы использовала скобки в первой его части и точку с запятой — для смыслового разделения. Мне кажется, что в таком виде предложение лучше для восприятия.

*Однако действующие лица, словно сошедшие с триумфального римского рельефа (те же ракурсы в полупрофиль, так же щедро струятся потоки одежд), приближены к нам; мы пока ещё не видим фигуры, как это будет впоследствии принято, в полный рост.*